# data frame corrections with moving window

Tags: r

Problem: With a data frame like:

```
df <- data.frame('ID'  = c(1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2),
                 'UD'  = c(0,   5,   10,  15,  0,   0,   10,  15),
                 'LD'  = c(5,   10,  15,  20,  5,   10,  15,  20),
                 'VAL' = c(1.2, 3.6, 5.7, 8.0, 5.2, 5.6, 8.7, 3.1))
```

for each ID group, the value of LD must match the value of UD on the next row down. So `df[6, 2]` should be 5, not 0.

I've been trying to write a function that can move through a data frame like this one and make that kind of correction. I think I've gotten close with the following, but the edited value is being overwritten as `rollapply` reassembles its outputs.

```
fix <- function(df) {
  df2 <- by(df, as.factor(df$ID), FUN = function(x) {

    rollapply(x, width = 2, FUN = function(y) {

      y[2, 2] <- ifelse(y[2, 2] != y[1, 3], y[1, 3], y[2, 2])
      print(y) #  test
      return(y)

      }, by.column = FALSE)
    print('x:') # test
    print(x)    # test
    return(x)
  })

  out <- do.call('rbind', df2)
  return(out)

  }
```

Is there a way to fix this, or a better alternative approach to the issue?

edit - expected output:

```
df2 <- data.frame('ID'  = c(1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2),
                  'UD'  = c(0,   5,   10,  15,  0,   5,   10,  15),
                  'LD'  = c(5,   10,  15,  20,  5,   10,  15,  20),
                  'VAL' = c(1.2, 3.6, 5.7, 8.0, 5.2, 5.6, 8.7, 3.1))
```

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`. Group the data by 'ID', then set 'UD' to be the same as 'LD', but shifted by one (using `mutate` and `lag`). When you get to a new 'ID', set that first one to 0 (NA is the default).

```
library(dplyr)

fixed_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(UD = lag(LD, default = 0))
fixed_df

#Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
#Groups: ID [2]
# 
#     ID    UD    LD   VAL
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     5   1.2
#2     1     5    10   3.6
#3     1    10    15   5.7
#4     1    15    20   8.0
#5     2     0     5   5.2
#6     2     5    10   5.6
#7     2    10    15   8.7
#8     2    15    20   3.1
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'ID', we assign (`:=`) the `lag` of 'LD' (`shift`) as the 'UD' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, UD := shift(LD, fill=0), by = ID]
df
#    ID UD LD VAL
#1:  1  0  5 1.2
#2:  1  5 10 3.6
#3:  1 10 15 5.7
#4:  1 15 20 8.0
#5:  2  0  5 5.2
#6:  2  5 10 5.6
#7:  2 10 15 8.7
#8:  2 15 20 3.1
```

Comment: Neat, thanks. I'll stick with the dplyr approach just because I'm fairly unfamiliar with data.table.